# Is there anyway to print both int and str without using f strings or str()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to achieve a print where it outputs longest line and the words associated with it.

```
with open("txt.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        words_count += len(words)
        if maxlines == 0 or len(words) > len(maxlines.split()):
            maxlines = line
        sentences.append(line)

print("Longest line has " + maxlines_len + " words: " + maxlines)
```

The variable will spit out a typeError if I declare its value it without str(). Is there any workarounds without fstrings or str()?

Thank you!

Comment: `print(int,str,whatever)` like that

Comment: `print("Longest line has  ", maxlines_len, "  words:  ",  maxlines)`

Comment: `ftypes` as in f-strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't sum strings and integers, but `print()` happily accepts any number of arguments and will stringify them internally (and separate them with spaces by default; you can control that with the `sep=` keyword argument):

```
print("Longest line has", maxlines_len, "words:", maxlines)
```

If using f-string formatting was an option (not sure why you wouldn't use them):

```
print(f"Longest line has {maxlines_len} words: {maxlines}")
```

Comment: No, no it doesn't.

Comment: @Kururin then you didn't do it like the posted